# Return value received in anonymous method inside function

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I have a Javascript function that uses the google API.  I want this function to either return the status if there is an error or return the place object if request was OK.

My attempt isn't right because I am specifying the return value inside the anonymous method.  I am not sure how to pass up this return value.  This is my attempt:

```
function GetDetail(id)
{
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#results').get(0));

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: id
    }, function (place, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
            return place;
        }
        else {      
            return status;
        }
    });

}

var myReturnObj = GetDetail(1234);
```

If I declare return value at top of function I still can't return it as the anonymous function does not return instantly so the GetDetail() method returns before it is set.  Same with `var return = service.getDetails()`

I am not sure on the proper way to write this.  I have tried various different things but I am confusing myself now.

How do I get GetDetail() to return the place/status object?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks or promises since you can't return from an async call (this is async nature in JS) - here's how you'd use a callback:

```
function GetDetail(id, callback) {
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#results').get(0));
    service.getDetails({placeId: id}, function (place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {     
            callback(place);
        } else {      
            callback(status);
        }
    });
}

GetDetail(1234, function(resp) {
    var myReturnObj = resp; //do your work in here!
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually declaring `myReturnObj` in C# code and invoking the javascript to get the return value so having a separate callback is a bit confusing keeping track of what is going back and forth, I'd ideally like all this to happen in same function to make life simpler.  Can I specify the return value inside a promise inside the GetDetail() function?

Comment: No, you can't do this the way you are trying to. You need to work with JavaScript as it actually works. You have a JavaScript callback function that receives the places data. Now have your C# code expose a method that can be called from JavaScript code. Call this method from the JavaScript callback. You can create an ID of some sort in the initiating C# code and pass it along through the whole process if you want to keep track of which response came from which request.

Answer (score 0):

This is why Promises are awesome. 
AND ES6, ES7, and the new version of Node.js are going to rely on them heavily.

You can say:

```
GetDetail(1234).then(function(info){
  var myInf0 = info;
//then do what you want with it...
  res.render('page', {info: myInfo})
}
```

or:

```
GetDetail(1234)
.then(function(info){
    return db.insert({_id: info.id, stuff: info.arrayOfStuff})
.then(function(){
    return db.findOne({_id: info.id})
.then(function(){
     res.render('page', {id: info.id})
})
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use a promise to make GetDetails return value after the anonymous function has completed?  This would let me have a single function I can call from my C#

Comment: Also, if you are passing the Promise a  return value.. it will not fire unless that value is present.. It looks like your inner function if else is handling that.        ...In reference to the comment above....you can pass normally chain a then inside the GetDetails function which would do what you are looking for...however because you are interacting with google maps..promises may not be supported.  But its worth a try!  add a .then( )

Comment: Promises aren't more efficient than callbacks: promises *use* callbacks. They are merely another way to organize and call your callbacks in a way that can let you write cleaner code. @Guerrilla: Promises don't help you here. You may end up wanting to use them, but they don't add any new capability to the JavaScript language that isn't already there. See my other comment and think in terms of callbacks: Your C# code calls a JavaScript function which starts an asynchronous request with a callback. That JavaScript callback calls a method in your C# code.